# Cannot read property '$apply' of null when set angularCompileRows to true

Tags: angularjs, ag-grid

I use AngularJS 1.7 and ag-grid 18.0.1.

When I set angularCompileRows  to true, I have this error in the console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '$apply' of null
at eval (rowRenderer.js:586)
```

This is the code corresponding (this is agGrid code):

```
RowRenderer.prototype.checkAngularCompile = function () {
    var _this = this;
    // if we are doing angular compiling, then do digest the scope here
    if (this.gridOptionsWrapper.isAngularCompileRows()) {
        // we do it in a timeout, in case we are already in an apply
        setTimeout(function () {
            _this.$scope.$apply();
        }, 0);
    }
};
```

Here my options:

```
const gridOptions = {
            rowData: null,
            columnDefs: [...],
            enableColResize: true,
            onColumnResized: (params) => {
            angularCompileRows: true,
            suppressCellSelection: true,
            enableSorting: true,
            enableServerSideSorting: true,
            rowModelType: 'infinite',
            pagination: true,
            paginationPageSize: 10,
            unSortIcon: true,
            suppressPaginationPanel: true,
            suppressHorizontalScroll: true,
            onGridReady: (params) => {
                const dataSource = {
                    rowCount: null, // behave as infinite scroll
                    getRows: (rowsParams) => {
                        // call my API then rowsParams.successCallback(data, isLastPage);
                    },
                };

                gridOptions.api.setDatasource(dataSource);
            },
        };
```

The call stack

[image]

And the output of the debug option

[image]

The grid is rendering: headers are okay, but the content is empty.

Plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/j5ubZWit4CO5zmldgqnl?p=preview based on this exemple https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-infinite-scrolling/#example-2-equal-pagination-page-size-and-large-infinite-block-si and add `angularCompileRows: true` to options

**EDIT:** Here a plunker with an angular app https://plnkr.co/edit/7eOKSXbcCzLdYWtPygrS?p=preview

The error is not fired but the angularCompileRows do not seem to be called

Comment: @AlekseySolovey the code with `$scope.$apply` is the agGrid code, it's not mine

Comment: The problem is likely caused by something earlier in the code stack. Examine the entire call stack to determine the origin of the problem.

Comment: @georgeawg I've had a screenshot of the call stack, if that help. Currently tring to debug it ;)

Comment: the Plunker you provided is not an angularjs app, could you provide your angularjs app that producing the error?

Comment: @PeterWilson i've added a plunker (see my edit). Sorry for this mistake... In my project I'm sure I use an angularjs app, and I have still this error... I don't know how to reproduce it.

Comment: @EloHailwidis in your angularjs example from plnkr you are using `angularCompileRow` instead of `angularCompileRows`, which is not correct.

Comment: @StanislavKvitash right ! Then I guess my question is useless now ... I get my code workking this morning, but I don't know why exactly. I obviously need some sleep ! Thanks ;)

Comment: @EloHailwidis that is great you were able to resolve the issue :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're going to use angular with the grid, why not load angular first :). You're not loading angular and you are not using any angular code in the grid, how is it suppose to call `$scope.$apply()` without that?

Make `angularCompileRows = false` and your grid works. If you're going to use angular, start with an angular example.

Comment: See my answer to PeterWilson ;) 
And I din't use an angular template in my exemple, but I need it, so I can't set the option to false